# Most efficient way to rename elements in dataframe of lists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary

I have two dataframes where one contains pet ID's and names, and the other user's and a list of the ID's of the pets they like. I'd like to get this into a dict where the keys are users, and the values being all the names of the pets they like.

```
    id  name
0   4   Bert
1   5   Ernie
2   6   Jeff
3   7   Bob
4   8   Puppy
5   9   Socks
6   12  Cyoot
```

```
    user_email  likes
0   matt@google.com [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12]
1   gabe@google.com [4, 8, 9, 6, 5, 12]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you can try:

```
d= df.set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()
df1.likes=df1.likes.apply(lambda x: [d.get(item,item)  for item in x])
print(df1)
```

---

```
        user_email                                          likes
0  matt@google.com  [Bert, Ernie, Jeff, Bob, Puppy, Socks, Cyoot]
1  gabe@google.com       [Bert, Puppy, Socks, Jeff, Ernie, Cyoot]
```

For a dict to have likes against a email:

```
print(df1.set_index('user_email')['likes'].to_dict())

{'matt@google.com': ['Bert', 'Ernie', 'Jeff', 'Bob', 'Puppy', 'Socks', 'Cyoot'],\
  'gabe@google.com': ['Bert', 'Puppy', 'Socks', 'Jeff', 'Ernie', 'Cyoot']}
```

Comment: This looks good, I have a hunch the only reason it isn't working for me off the bat is that the elements of those lists are actually type str, and the keys of that dict are getting set as ints.

Comment: To clarify, the list itself is actually a list, just the elements inside of them are strings

Comment: @zintj then what if you do `d= df.astype(str).set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()` and then try this? Just guessing it should work

Answer (score 1):

first. set the pet id to be the index:

```
pets.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

than, apply for each 'likes' list a function, to replace each like with a the corresponding pet name:

```
users.likes = users.likes.map(lambda likes: [pets.loc[like]['name'] for like in likes])
```

finally - all you have to do is make your dataframe to a dictionary:

```
users.set_index('user_email').to_dict()['likes']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `likes` column in your 2nd dataframe is of type `list` we can do the following:

**Unnest the list to rows**

```
df3 = df2.set_index('user_email').likes.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'likes'})

print(df3)
        user_email  likes
0  matt@google.com    4.0
1  matt@google.com    5.0
2  matt@google.com    6.0
3  matt@google.com    7.0
4  matt@google.com    8.0
5  matt@google.com    9.0
6  matt@google.com   12.0
0  gabe@google.com    4.0
1  gabe@google.com    8.0
2  gabe@google.com    9.0
3  gabe@google.com    6.0
4  gabe@google.com    5.0
5  gabe@google.com   12.0
```

**Merge the names to the dataframe**

```
df4 = df3.merge(df1, left_on='likes', right_on='id').drop(['likes', 'id'],axis=1)

print(df4)
         user_email   name
0   matt@google.com   Bert
1   gabe@google.com   Bert
2   matt@google.com  Ernie
3   gabe@google.com  Ernie
4   matt@google.com   Jeff
5   gabe@google.com   Jeff
6   matt@google.com    Bob
7   matt@google.com  Puppy
8   gabe@google.com  Puppy
9   matt@google.com  Socks
10  gabe@google.com  Socks
11  matt@google.com  Cyoot
12  gabe@google.com  Cyoot
```

**Convert the rows back to list with `groupby`**

```
df_final = df4.groupby('user_email').agg(list).reset_index()

print(df_final)
        user_email                                           name
0  gabe@google.com       [Bert, Ernie, Jeff, Puppy, Socks, Cyoot]
1  matt@google.com  [Bert, Ernie, Jeff, Bob, Puppy, Socks, Cyoot]
```